# How can I Print label from database select result using loop

Tags: c#, printing

I've to say this first , I'm new to windows programming,

I have got a requirement to print a set of results getting from a search query. Each resulted row should be printed on individual labels . A sample result set is included in the query. What is the best way achieving this.The **barcode** column shown should printed as bar code and the other two columns should print above and below the label.
Normally we may have to print up to 500 labels in a single button click.

Below I've added the code I'm working with. In the page load event I'm passing the ID to load data for a specific item from database. But I need to make it automated with a selected list of items, not a single one.
[Result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPPKx.png)

```
public partial class PrintLabel : Form
    {
        string s_desc = "";
        string s_date = "";
        Image bCodeImage;

        public PrintLabel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void PrintLabel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillData(735);
        }
        private void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ItemPrint();
            this.Close();
        }
        void FillData(int ID)
        {
            string str = Properties.Settings.Default.ConW;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
            {
                try
                {
                    string query = "select item.ID+'-'+item.ItemLookupCode as Barcode,ExtendedDescription,GETDATE()+180 Expiry from Item where ID=" + ID + ";";
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    SqlDataReader dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dtr.Read())
                    {
                        GenerateBarcode(dtr[0].ToString());
                        s_desc = dtr[1].ToString();
                        s_date = dtr[2].ToString();
                        lblDescription.Text = s_desc;
                        lblExpiry.Text = s_date;
                        PBBarcode.Image = bCodeImage;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        private void GenerateBarcode(string _bCodeImage)
        {
            string barCode = _bCodeImage;
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(barCode.Length * 60, 750);
            using (Graphics grapics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                Font ofont = new System.Drawing.Font("IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode", 14);
                PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush white = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                grapics.FillRectangle(white, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
                grapics.DrawString("*" + barCode + "*", ofont, black, point);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                bCodeImage = bitmap;
            }
        }

        private void ItemPrint()
        {
            PrintDialog printdg = new PrintDialog();
            if (printdg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
                pd.PrinterSettings = printdg.PrinterSettings;
                pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
                pd.Print();
                pd.Dispose();
            }
        }
        private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            lblDescription.Text = s_desc;
            lblExpiry.Text = s_date;
            PBBarcode.InitialImage = bCodeImage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem here? What technology are you using? Is it a ASP.NET application on desktop application? Also consider reading [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you need to print on paper then you should go with some reporting SDK (Crystal reports, Report sharp shooter etc)

Comment: What language do you use? Do you have any code? You need to print this on screen or paper?

Comment: I'm using C# for programming.

Comment: I'll add my code with the question ...

Comment: @Michael - This is for label, of size 2.25*1.25 inches size

Comment: @Alexander we have printed the labels with SharpShooter: it has a barcode fonts, page properties etc. You may also use other repoting frameworks. The general idea is to make a template in reports designer, then pass your data to report and then you can display it or print.

Comment: @Michael - That seems a good idea. Let me try :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've achieved it using the below code, posting as it may help some one in the future.

```
private void PrintLabelVal()
        {
            string str = Properties.Settings.Default.con;
            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(str);


            string query = " SELECT TempLotUpdate.Quantity,Item.BinLocation,Item.ItemLookupCode," +
                            " Item.ExtendedDescription,Item.LotNumber," +
                            " Item.ExpiryDate " +
                            " FROM TempLotUpdate" +
                             " INNER JOIN Item ON TempLotUpdate.ItemId = Item.ID" +

                            " WHERE TempLotUpdate.PONumber = '" + Globals.s_PON + "'; ";
            int cnt = 0;
            int var = 0;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Conn);
            try
            {
                Conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    cnt = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][0]);
                    var = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][4]);
                    for (var j = 0; j < cnt; j++)
                    {
                        var = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][4]);
                        print(var); // Passing Lot ID
                    }
                }
             }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void print(int obj)
        {
            FillData(obj);
            ItemPrint();
            this.Close();
        }
        void FillData(int ID)
        {
            string str = Properties.Settings.Default.con;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
            {
                try
                {
                    string query = "SELECT ItemLookupCode BarCode,Description,ExpiryDate,BinLocation,Price " +
                                   " FROM Item where ID = " + ID + ";";
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    SqlDataReader dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dtr.Read())
                    {

                        barCode = dtr[0].ToString();
                        s_desc = dtr[1].ToString();
                        s_date = dtr[2].ToString();
                        s_BinLoc = dtr[3].ToString();
                        s_Price = dtr[4].ToString();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ItemPrint()
        {
            PrintDialog printdg = new PrintDialog();
            if (printdg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
                pd.PrinterSettings = printdg.PrinterSettings;
                pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
                pd.Print();
                pd.Dispose();
            }
        }
        private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            string _desc = s_desc;
            var _g = e.Graphics;
            _g.DrawString(_desc, new Font("Arial Black", 7), Brushes.Black, 5, 8);

            string _bCode = "*"+barCode+"*";
            var _f = e.Graphics;
            _f.DrawString(_bCode, new Font("IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode", 8), Brushes.Black, 4, 25);

            string _BinLoc = s_BinLoc;
            var _i = e.Graphics;
            _i.DrawString(_BinLoc, new Font("Arial Narrow", 7), Brushes.Black, 5, 75);

            string _date = "Exp: " + s_date.Substring(0, 10);
            var _h = e.Graphics;         
            _h.DrawString(_date, new Font("Arial Narrow", 7), Brushes.Black, 45, 75);

            string _Price = s_Price;
            var _j = e.Graphics;         
            _j.DrawString(_Price, new Font("Arial Narrow", 7), Brushes.Black, 120, 75);
        }
```